# Geoserver REST API: Duplicate layer name

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

Using the web admin page, I created two layers in different workspace but with the same name:

In the admin view I see something as this

```
Workspace  Store        Layer Name
WK1        PostGIS1     mylayer
WK2        PostGIS2     mylayer
```

All works very well, except when I try to access the properties of these layers with Geoserver REST API.

/layers.xml give me something like:

```
<layer><name>mylayer</name><atom:link rel="alternate" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/mylayer.xml" type="application/xml"/></layer>
<layer><name>mylayer</name><atom:link rel="alternate" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/mylayer.xml" type="application/xml"/></layer>
```

Two identical entries! And when I ask for the layer with /layers/mylayer.xml I only get the properties of the first...

How can I access the properties of the second layer with the REST API? Can it be done or it's a limitation or a bug of the REST API?

Comment: I'm using Geoserver 2.4.4, but haven't seen any differences in the REST API documentation in version 2.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could be - it would be useful if /geoserver/rest/layers returned the workspace qualified names, such as:

```
<layer><name>mylayer</name><atom:link rel="alternate" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/WK1:mylayer.xml" type="application/xml"/></layer>
<layer><name>mylayer</name><atom:link rel="alternate" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/WK2:mylayer.xml" type="application/xml"/></layer>
```

The GeoServer relationship between workspace, stores, and layers (featureType resource in REST API) confuses me a bit.

If you just want to access the second layer, try using the workspace qualifier:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/WK1:mylayer
```

(I'm using GeoServer 2.5.1)

This is similar to the questions:

- Given a layer, what is its workspace?
- How do I find all layers in a workspace?

Best...

Comment: You're right, the command with the workspace qualifier works. Thanks.